# Set a cronjob from perl script

Tags: linux, perl, cron

I want to write the following bash script to perl

```
#write out current crontab
crontab -l > mycron
#echo new cron into cron file
echo "00 09 * * 1-5 echo hello" >> mycron
#install new cron file
crontab mycron
rm mycron
```

In perl, when I convert to

```
my $cronjobs = `crontab -l`;
my $raw = "00 09 * * 1-5 echo hello";
$cronjobs .= $raw;
say `crontab $cronjobs`;
```

but the above perl doesn't work. why ?

Comment: @simbabqueThe question is about perl script. not bash script.

Comment: Anything you can do from bash, you can do from Perl too.

Comment: I am a beginner in perl.

Comment: Why use Perl then?

Comment: The project is written in perl already.